# how to remove this click action javascript from the combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, combobox

The below is my code but i just want to implement simple combobox without the click. I mean i want to remove it in html and also in jquery. If i remove

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>
```

then which jquery code should i remove in the above code

```js
$(function(){
    var CB = $("select").kendoComboBox();
  
    $("a").click(function(){
       
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <select>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the click action, just do :

```
$('a').off('click');
```

`.on()` add listener
`.click()` is equal to `.on('click')`
`.off()` remove listener

In your above code, if you don't want the click listener just remove the click part :

```
$("a").click(function(){

});
```

So your jquery function will look like this :

```
$(function(){
    var CB = $("select").kendoComboBox();
});
```

Comment: can u edit in the code snippet for better understand or re edit the full jquery code which i need to add.....?

Answer (score 1):

can you please try with following HTML and Jquery snipptes.

```
<select id="mySelectBox">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Click</button>

$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#mySelectBox option:selected").remove();
});
```